# How to pause the program until we get the result of asynchoronous method?

Tags: asynchronous, windows-phone-8

I'm developing that need to use a asynchoronous method. I know my program will not pause to wait the result of that method. But my program must have the result of that method to continue. So, how can I pause my program until I get the result of that method? Otherwise, I need to synchronize a program that contains asynchronous methods.

This is my code:

```
private async void DiaChiGanNhat()
    {
        double kc;

        Geolocator myGeolocator = new Geolocator();
        Geoposition myGeoposition = await myGeolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
        Geocoordinate myGeocoordinate = myGeoposition.Coordinate;
        GeoCoordinate myGeoCoordinate = ConvertGeocoordinate(myGeocoordinate);

        IList<DiaChi> dc = dc_control.LocTheoTheLoai(TheLoai(txtTimKiem.Text));
        for (int i = 0; i < dc.Count; i++)
        {
            kc = TinhKhoangCach(myGeoCoordinate.Longitude, myGeoCoordinate.Latitude, dc[i].KinhDo, dc[i].ViDo);
            distance[i] = kc;
        }

        //sap xep tang dan ve khoang cach va ID
        for (int i = 0; i < distance.Length; i++)
        {
            if (distance[i] > distance[i + 1])
            {
                double tg1 = distance[i];
                distance[i] = distance[i + 1];
                distance[i + 1] = tg1;

                int tg2 = id[i];
                id[i] = id[i + 1];
                id[i + 1] = tg2;
            }
        }
    }
private void bttTimKiem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DiaChiGanNhat();
        IList<DiaChi> addr1 = dc_control.LocTheoID(id[0]);
        txtDiaChi1.Text = addr1[0].TenDiaChi;

        IList<DiaChi> addr2 = dc_control.LocTheoID(id[1]);
        txtDiaChi2.Text = addr2[0].TenDiaChi;

        IList<DiaChi> addr3 = dc_control.LocTheoID(id[2]);
        txtDiaChi3.Text = addr3[0].TenDiaChi;
    }
```

That's my problem. I must pause my program until the method DiaChiGanNhat() finish.
Don't worry about the method name, cuz I'm Vietnamese. LOL

Thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: Why would you want to pause the program to wait for an **async** task? You might as well make it a **sync** task.

Comment: Of course, I don't wanna use asynchronous method. But this method GetGeopositionAsync() is a asynchronous method. ^_^

Comment: You're not supposed to block the UI thread like that on the Windows Phone platform. Instead, design your UI so that it is showing something ("Loading..." or whatever) while the operation is in progress, and have it transition to the normal state when the operation completes.

Comment: I just have an idea that I don't need to use this method. Just click on the map, then get the coordinate of that point. Not bad! ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this using a `Wait`, which will block on that method until it's finished:

```
private void bttTimKiem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(DiaChiGanNhat);
        task.Wait();  

        IList<DiaChi> addr1 = dc_control.LocTheoID(id[0]);
        txtDiaChi1.Text = addr1[0].TenDiaChi;

        IList<DiaChi> addr2 = dc_control.LocTheoID(id[1]);
        txtDiaChi2.Text = addr2[0].TenDiaChi;

        IList<DiaChi> addr3 = dc_control.LocTheoID(id[2]);
        txtDiaChi3.Text = addr3[0].TenDiaChi;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using await when calling the function should work.

Try

```
await DiaChiGanNhat();
```

do read the comment below.

Comment: `async` methods of type void cannot be awaited. To do that use `Task` instead of `void` on `DiaChiGanNhat()` method.